# Get file name from File Path in python

Tags: python, variables

This Question Already have a solution but In my case I'm not getting the correct solution where am I getting wrong?

```
import os,sys
filename = "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ProjectShadow\app2\aapp2s.py"
directory, module_name = os.path.split(filename)
module_name = os.path.splitext(module_name)[0]
print(module_name)
print(directory)
```

[image: I get following Result]

Insterd I want

```
>> 
aapp2s
C:\User\Dell\Desktop
```

What's Wrong ?

Comment: you're missing the raw prefix `r"C:\users\...`. `\a` is a special escape sequence.

Comment: Backslashes in string literals should be escaped. e.g. `"C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\ProjectShadow\\app2\\aapp2s.py"`, or use `r` prefix, e.g. `r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ProjectShadow\app2\aapp2s.py"`

Answer (score 2):

either use `r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ProjectShadow\app2\aapp2s.py"` or you can double backshlash the whole thing `"C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\ProjectShadow\\app2\\aapp2s.py"`

The strange thing you see on your print is the result of the \a escape char

Comment: what if link is stored in a variable ? how do i use regular expression r' ? with variable??

Comment: @amitnair92 well you can use something like `newText = "%r"%textFromVariable`

Answer (score 0):

Try `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
filename = r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ProjectShadow\app2\aapp2s.py"
p = PureWindowsPath(filename)
module_name = p.stem
directory = p.parents[2]
print(module_name)
print(directory)
```

out:

```
aapp2s
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop
```